# Java PriorityQueue Seems to Change Previously Added Values on Calling add()

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I am left puzzled as the priority queue I am working with seems to change or reorder the previously added values in a loop while adding new values. It only happens with this test case so far.

Here are some snips of my debugger:

Before adding 6th element:

[image]

After adding 6th element:

[image]

The code example is as follows:

```
package mixedobjectsset;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MixedObjectsSet {

private static final char union = '\u222A';
private static final char intersection = '\u2229';
private static final char product = '\u2A2F';
private static final char difference = '\u2216';


public static void main(String[] args) {
    MixedObjectsSet m = new MixedObjectsSet();
    m.operatorsQueue("(({1,2}" + difference + "{1,3})" +
            difference + "({1 } " + union + "{4})) " + union + "{1,3}");
}

public Queue operatorsQueue(String expr){

    Queue<Character> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    char[] exprCharArr = expr.toCharArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < exprCharArr.length; j++) {
        switch (exprCharArr[j]){
            case '(':
                queue.add('(');
                break;
            case ')':
                queue.add(')');
                break;
            case '\u222A':
                queue.add(union);
                break;
            case '\u2216':
                queue.add(difference);
                break;
            case '\u2A2F':
                queue.add(product);
                break;
            case '\u2229':
                queue.add(intersection);
                break;
            case ';':
                queue.add(';'); //for adding to storage instead of calculations
                break;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("queue.toString() = " + queue.toString());

    return queue;


   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array `queue` in `PriorityQueue` implementation does NOT store elements in the order they will be polled out of the queue. `PriorityQueue` is a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), and the heap is stored in `queue` array as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation). It means that you should not look in the `queue` array (unless you know how binary heap exactly works), because it's an **encapsulated** implementation detail that does a different thing that you may expect from its name.

Comment: Actually "you should not look in the queue array" is a little harsh. Printing the array (which is what the underlying collection `.toString()` does) or using a debugger to look at it is fine. Just ignore the order. As you say, it's an abstract data type.

Comment: I strongly believed its FIFO. It is not, I see. Thank you

Comment: @Gene especially, as `toString()`, part of the public API, will reveal the internal order, as well as iterating over it or calling `toArray()` to get a copy (after all, it’s a `Collection` implementation), so it’s more constructive to point to [the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) saying “*The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.*” So you may look at it, but not expect a particular order.

Comment: @Holger Got that. I'm just pointing out that it's fine to be concerned with contents and not order. Sets are in the same boat.